# ElasticSearch possibility to search for a mixed "Tables"

Tags: elasticsearch, amplifyjs

I have two tables in DynamoD, one (jobs) is streamed to ElasticSearch.

I have:

jobs:

```
{
id,
name,
location,
interactions: [interact]
}

interact:
{
id,
user,
job
}
```

If I now request them via GraphQL, I get a connection of jobs and interact. So something like this:
job:

```
{
id,
name,
interactios: [
 {
  id,
  users
 }
...
]
}
```

I would like to request all jobs that the user has not yet seen. 
If I do this via GraphQL now, I get an array with 100 jobs, but in every job the user can theoretically be under interactios and the array would be empty after filtering.

Can't I just stream interactions to elasticsearch and start a query:

Give me all jobs in the near AND UserID must not be in the interactions list belongs to this job

Comment: this will be very non trivial to maintain all the previous transaction.